# Differences in p-values between general linear model, t-test and non-parametric test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value, linear-model

Sometimes I face problems in the lab for which I am not able to come up with a sensible answer, due to my lack of statistical knowledge. In this case, I have an answer, but I am not very sure if I am totally right, so I would like to describe my approximation and ask the community if it makes sense at all.

I am currently analyzing some gene expression data coming from an experiment on a set of cell lines.

The data (after being anonymized) looks like this:

```
|ID   |Type   |     Value|
|:----|:------|---------:|
|Id_1 |Type_1 |  1.064256|
|Id_2 |Type_1 |  1.000000|
|Id_3 |Type_1 |  1.016967|
|Id_4 |Type_1 |  1.249208|
|Id_5 |Type_1 |  1.659668|
|Id_6 |Type_1 |  1.876265|
|Id_7 |Type_1 |  1.169406|
|Id_1 |Type_2 |  3.030309|
|Id_2 |Type_2 |  4.001117|
|Id_3 |Type_2 |  3.383119|
|Id_4 |Type_2 | 14.293665|
|Id_5 |Type_2 |  3.359315|
|Id_6 |Type_2 |  5.760926|
|Id_7 |Type_2 |  3.197459|
|Id_1 |Type_3 |  2.517612|
|Id_2 |Type_3 |  1.943949|
|Id_3 |Type_3 |  2.211084|
|Id_4 |Type_3 |  1.772899|
|Id_5 |Type_3 |  5.767478|
|Id_6 |Type_3 |  3.487883|
|Id_7 |Type_3 |  2.019733|
```

Some boxplots:[image: Expression data]

The researcher is asking if there are any statistically significant differences between the three types. More precisely, she wants to know if there are differences between a) Type_2 and Type_1 and b) Type_3 and Type_1. This is a very simple experiment with Type_1 as a reference group.

It can also be considered that the measures are paired if we take the ID variable into account. But in this question I am going to ignore that for the sake of clarity.

I am using general linear models throughout the whole analysis, that comprises this and other questions. I have to admit that there is possibly a emotional bias involved, since this kind of models are quite intuitive for me. So, I proceed and fit a linear model to the previous data.

```
> fit = lm(Value ~ Type, data = foo)
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Value ~ Type, data = foo)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.2591 -1.0443 -0.2908  0.3688  9.0042 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   1.2908     0.9453   1.365  0.18893   
TypeType_2    3.9986     1.3369   2.991  0.00784 **
TypeType_3    1.5264     1.3369   1.142  0.26853   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.501 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3361,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2623 
F-statistic: 4.556 on 2 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.02506
```

By looking at the previous output, I told the researcher that there was a significant difference between the Type_2 and Type_1 groups, but **not** between the Type_3 and Type_1, despite the fact that graphically it seems that both Type_2 and Type_3 are different from the reference group.

The researcher did not like the result, as she was expecting both comparisons to be statistically significant. So she asked me to do some t-tests on the same data.

```
> t.test(Value ~ Type, data = foo, subset = foo$Type != 'Type_3')

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Value by Type
t = -2.5849, df = 6.0849, p-value = 0.04097
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -7.7709913 -0.2261915
sample estimates:
mean in group Type_1 mean in group Type_2 
            1.290824             5.289416
```

Looking at the t-test result, we could say that there is a significant difference between Type_2 and Type_1. This is coherent with the linear model. What happens if we test the second hypothesis?

```
> t.test(Value ~ Type, data = foo, subset = foo$Type != 'Type_2')

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  Value by Type
t = -2.7643, df = 6.6979, p-value = 0.02919
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2.8441619 -0.2086578
sample estimates:
mean in group Type_1 mean in group Type_3 
            1.290824             2.817234
```

Things are getting interesting. The result from this second t-test says that there is a significant difference between Type_3 and Type_1. Moreover, the p-value is smaller than the p-value for the first hypothesis. This is quite the contrary to what the results from the linear model are describing.

The researcher asked me if I could explain what was happening. I told her **first** that different methods can yield different results, especially when we are near the limit of statistical significance, and **second**, that the linear model approximation takes into account the variance of the whole dataset, even when it is testing a difference between two levels of a variable. I argued that the relationship between the variances (within and between groups) might be influencing the standard error computations and thus the final p-values.

With this in mind, I am wondering about a couple facts:

- Is the linear model approximation a good approach for this analysis or am I committing a terrible mistake?
- If the t-test or Wilcoxon (not shown, similar to the t-test) are generating positive results, why do we obtain such a high p-value (0.26853) for the corresponding coefficient in the linear model?
- Why such a penalization on the standard error for the Type_3 coefficient in the linear model when there is clearly much more variance in the Type_2 group?

Hope somebody can help me understand this to a greater extent. Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too large for my mobile to answer, so I will add just a random selection of thoughts:

- to get reasonable p values by linear model in a small sample ANOVA setting, you need similar group variances, approx. normal distribution and independence. All three assumptions seem to be grossly violated, so as a reviewer, I would not accept such results at all. Appropriate methods could include Wilcoxon signed-rank tests on the within-subject differences, amongst others.
- Welch's version of the t-test tries to correct for unequal variance, so it is a bit less inappropriate than classic t-tests of the linear model. This is one reason why you got different results by the linear model. The other reason you have already mentioned (variance pooling over three groups instead over two).
- multiple testing issue is not mentioned at all

Comment: First of all, let me thank you for your helpful and informative answer. I understand the reasons for not using the linear model. I have to confess that I generally do not pay enough attention to the general assumptions that every test must fulfill, maybe carried away and influenced by the general tendency to use more familiar techniques or the lack of proper statistical advice. I think I am going to continue my analysis with non-parametric tests, due to the small sample size and differences in variability.

Comment: About multiple testing. I deliberately omitted the subject from the question in order not to complicate it more. I understand that if we are making the two comparisons on this dataset, the resulting p-values must be corrected using a proper technique. But the problem is similar to the one that originated the question, especially if the correction makes the comparison go against the main researcher intuition. What I usually do is to provide the researcher with both the unadjusted and adjusted p-values, so they can see how the evaluation of multiple hypotheses affects their results.

Comment: Good points. In your specific setting, switching to a paired (within-subject) strategy will help a lot. But I am aware that your question was about pairwise t-tests versus t-tests on parameters of linear models.

Comment: Main question was about understanding why my approximation was a bad one. And you helped a lot. Even from mobile. ;) Sometimes some of the most basic principles get entangled in my head and I need a helping hand just to see clearly where I am standing and why. Thank you again. I am now facing other problems related to non-parametric methods and small sample sizes, but that might be another question.